# F# loop through List.CountBy

Tags: .net, f#

I am attempting to loop through the list group at the end. How can I iterate through a group by list and apply a function to the count:

```
open System

module MonteCarlo = 

    let processMin = 14
    let processMax = 21
    let randInt = new Random()
    let sampleCount = 10
    let results = [for i in 1 .. sampleCount -> (randInt.Next(processMin, processMax))] |> List.map(fun x-> float x)
    let MCResults = List.average results
    let MCTotal = List.sum results
    printfn "%A" MCResults
    let groups = List.countBy(fun i -> int i) results
    printfn "%A" groups
    groups |> List.iter( value from count / MCTotal)
```

Comment: For the last line just use `List.map` - `groups |> List.map ( fun (v,c) -> ( v / x, c / y))`

Comment: thank you @boran this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuddos to @boran for helping with the answer:

I used the following to access the items inside of the list:

```
open System

module MonteCarlo = 

    let processMin = 14
    let processMax = 21
    let randInt = new Random()
    let sampleCount = 1000000
    let results = [for i in 1 .. sampleCount -> (randInt.Next(processMin, processMax))] |> List.map(fun x-> float x)
    let MCResults = List.average results
    let MCCount = float (List.length results)
    let MCTotal = float (List.sum results)
    printfn "%A" MCResults
    let groups = (List.countBy(fun i -> int i) results) |> List.map ( fun (v,c) -> ( v, Math.Round(float (c *100) / MCCount,2)))
    printfn "%A" groups
    groups |> List.iter( fun (v,c) -> (printfn "%A %A%%" v c))
```